# Loading correct image to detail view

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I have a TableView app that plays music. The tracks are named: 0.mp3, 1.mp3 etc. They play in a detail view where I also want an image of the cover. I named the cover images: 0.png, 1.png etc.

I tried to load the correct image with the code:

```
self.bookImage.image = UIImage(named: ("/\(trackID!).png"))
```

but it doesn't work.

Here's some more of my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class AudioPlayerVC: UIViewController {

    var trackID: Int!
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

    @IBOutlet var bookImage: UIImageView! 

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if !audioPlayer.isPlaying{
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.bookImage.image = UIImage(named: ("/\(trackID!).png"))
        trackLbl.text = "Track \(trackID!)"

        let path: String! = Bundle.main.resourcePath?.appending("/\(trackID!).mp3")
        let mp3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do
        {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: mp3URL as URL)
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
self.bookImage.image = UIImage(named:"\(trackID).png")
```

**Or**

```
self.bookImage.image = UIImage(named:"\(trackID)")
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :(. There's no error, but the ImageView is blank.

Comment: How do you attach the images to the project  ?? make sure that target membership is ticked for each image

Comment: They are. And I placed them in the same folder (don't know if that matters).

Comment: the folder is reference folder yellow or blue ??

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `/` character after opening quotation mark.

`self.bookImage.image = UIImage(named:"\(trackID).png")`

Should work just fine.

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Please add your images to Assets.xcassets

2) Name images like 0,1,2,3 in Assets.xcassets

3) Write a code:

```
let trackId = String(trackId)
self.bookImage.image = UIImage(named: trackId)
```

Comment: Thanx, will use assets from now on :P